problem with UvRizom
I downloaded the trial version of UvRizom 2024, And I bought the Rizomuv Bridge addon - Blender 2.8+
(https://blendermarket.com/products/rizomuv-bridge)

In "RizomPath" I chose this path:

After clicking export, the following error appears:

What am I doing wrong?

Sorry but we can't help you with third-party commercial addons. This Q&A site can only help with problems using Blender and its built-in addons. Suggest you contact the addon's author(s).

Okay, I just thought that maybe someone also used this add-on and could answer me, thanks

@AlenaZhuravleva have you tried contacting the seller of this addon? They should be able to help you.

I tried it, I'm waiting for an answer, thanks
